# ASP.NET ReportViewer Expression returns error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I have a ASP.NET Report viewer.

In report I have the following expression:

```
="Total for Region: " & 
 iif(str(Fields!Region_Of_Responsibility.Value)="","No Region",Fields!Region_Of_Responsibility.Value)
```

In run time I return #Error.

Why this error happens and how find what this #Error means?

Comment: So from this code, you're getting the result of `Total for Region: #Error`?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this column can contain nulls, and if so, here's another way to tackle this one

```
="Total for Region: " & 
 iif(cstr(Fields!Region_Of_Responsibility.Value)="" or isDbNull(Fields!Region_Of_Responsibility.Value),"No Region",Fields!Region_Of_Responsibility.Value)
```

Comment: still getting Error

Comment: Fields!Region_Of_Responsibility.Value returns DBNull infact

Comment: oops, I have that str function still, try it with this edit!

Comment: Did that help?  Does it display as `Total for Region: #Error?`?